# PrimeNG fullcalendar: calling events on clicking prev and next button in fullcalendar Angular 2

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am using PrimeNG fullcalendar in angular 2, so far I am able to integrate with service and dynamicalyy populating the events, but I needed `onclick` event for month as similar to `onDayClick`.

Any help would be great

Comment: what you actually want to achive ?

Comment: I need to send current months start date and end date( for each month I have to populate the events) so is there any method for getting the navigated month's start date and end date

Comment: than why not get current date using javascript's `new Date()` and send wherever you want ?

Comment: I want the start date and end date of user's selected month i.e when the user navigates through the months.

Comment: than when you set the date selected by user to calendar , save those values in one variable and send it as it as isn't it ?

Comment: No, that's not what I want.

Let's suppose that the user have navigated to a specific month, via browser/javascript. I want to pass this month to the server-side so that I can populate that months event

Comment: Is this what you need? http://fiddle.jshell.net/sme2rmqg/

Comment: Thank you, I got it by using viewRender event